# Can't compile and link programs with clang

Tags: c, linker, clang

I recently compiled Clang 2.9 (from [here](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#2.9)) on an Ubuntu system. I'm having trouble compiling and linking a simple program. Does anyone know how to fix this? Here's the output I see:

```
a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ clang add.c
/usr/bin/ld: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 2 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**uname -a output**

```
Linux ubuntu 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

**gcc -v output:**

```
Using built-in specs.

COLLECT_GCC=gcc

COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/lto-wrapper

Target: i686-linux-gnu

Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4 --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.5 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --with-multiarch-defaults=i386-linux-gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.5 --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-gold --enable-ld=default --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu

Thread model: posix

gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)
```

**clang verbose ouput**

```
clang version 2.9 (tags/RELEASE_29/final)

Target: i386-pc-linux-gnu

Thread model: posix

"/usr/local/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple i386-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name add.c -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu pentium4 -target-linker-version 2.21.0.20110327 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -resource-dir /usr/local/bin/../lib/clang/2.9 -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 138 -fgnu-runtime -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /tmp/cc-JJruTv.o -x c add.c

clang -cc1 version 2.9 based upon llvm 2.9 hosted on i386-pc-linux-gnu

#include "..." search starts here:

#include <...> search starts here:

 /usr/local/include

 /usr/local/bin/../lib/clang/2.9/include

 /usr/include

End of search list.

 "/usr/bin/ld" --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o a.out crt1.o crti.o crtbegin.o -L -L/../../.. /tmp/cc-JJruTv.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed crtend.o crtn.o

/usr/bin/ld: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 2 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a problem in your linker script. But the ld line above does not contain a specific linker script so the default one should be used (to see it simply type `ld -v`).

`-L -L/../../..`
that does look a bit weird. Don't see it on your original line though so not sure where it came from. Perhaps your installation is broken?

Do a `gcc -v add.c` and compare the lines invoking `/usr/bin/ld`. Perhaps add it to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turned out `/usr/bin/ld` was overwritten with another file. I'm not sure how that happened, but by investigating the output of `gcc -v add.c`, I was able to make that determination. I ended up replacing /usr/bin/ld and got everything to work.