# Getting error as /tmp/checker-276/bin/clang failed with exit code 71 when analyzing the code using Xcode's built in analyzer

Tags: ios, xcode

When i am analysing the project using Xcode's static analyser i am getting following error:

**/tmp/checker-276/bin/clang failed with exit code 71**

I have tried lots of solutions, but couldn't fixed it.

Comment: change macho-linker to static library

Comment: check with link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7715807/5362916